# MVC web API identity impersonation

Tags: api, model-view-controller, impersonation

HI all I am developing a web API that will be using identity impersonation (using always the same  functional identity  valid in my domain) to check the status of configuration files of some servers. To do that, I add this to my web.config file

I also set my IIS server to neglate anonymous authentication and accept windows authentication for web service. However when I try to access the status of the files from a browser I noticed that the API is still using NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as the user and, of course, the access to the remote files is denied. Does anyone have an idea of what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to add my web.config file line <identity impersonate="true" userName="DOMAIN\User" password="pass_"/>

Answer (score 0):

My fault, forgot to set the Authentication mode to Windows in web.config